# Why I cannot install OpenAI Universe on MacOS?

Tags: openai-api

I've been trying to install OpenAI Universe with code 'pip install universe'

it shows error[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hy32I.jpg)

but I've installed golang and libjpeg-turbo already

```
(universe) a@YXHdeMacBook-Pro universe % brew install libjpeg-turbo golang
Warning: jpeg-turbo 2.0.6 is already installed and up-to-date
To reinstall 2.0.6, run `brew reinstall jpeg-turbo`
Warning: go 1.15.5 is already installed and up-to-date
To reinstall 1.15.5, run `brew reinstall go`
(universe) a@YXHdeMacBook-Pro universe %
```

Comment: From the SO Meta FAQ: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.